# Understanding constraints in regression / maximum likelihood

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, modeling, interpretation, constraint

There are many questions about implementing parameter constraints. My question is about understanding constraints. What follows is a very contrived example that I thought up on the spot. Feel free to suggest a better one!

Suppose you observe gun purchases in a town, and you figure that people decide to buy guns based on the levels of crime: crime goes up, people buy more guns; crime goes down, people buy fewer guns. Your model is

$$
\text{guns} = \alpha + \beta_{uc} \text{crime} + \epsilon.
$$

where $\beta_{uc}$ is the unconstrained coefficient.

However, the lower bound to gun purchases by an individual is zero - she can't buy negative guns. Therefore you re-parameterize the model to include an inequality constraint on $\beta$:

$$
\text{guns} = \alpha + \text{exp}(\beta_c) \text{crime} + \epsilon.
$$

where $\beta_{c}$ is the constrained coefficient.

Using least squares you estimate both models with appropriate controls on the error structure and other appropriate regressors. You find $\hat{\beta_{uc}} < 0$ and, as expected, $\hat{\beta_{c}} > 0$.

**Question 1**

How does one reconcile the fact that the inequality constraint forces the coefficient to be something it does not want to be? In other words, is the constrained model valid?

**Question 2**

Suppose instead you estimated the model using maximum likelihood. You couldn't say that this is the model that maximizes the likelihood of the data, could you? After all, as I understand it, this is constrained optimization.

**Motivation**

I read this [blog post](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/regression-with-interval-constraints/) by Stata where the author shows how to implement inequality constraints using ML. In the unconstrained model the coefficient in question is negative; in the constrained model it is, of course, positive. However, he says that after ML estimation one needs to use another command (`nlcom`) to find the estimates. When he does, the coefficient is negative! I didn't understand the point of the constraint.

Comment: Your rationale for the constraint is not correct: it *is* possible that as crime goes down, gun purchasing *or* ownership goes up and *vice versa*.

Comment: This is meant to be a toy example. I just want to imagine a situation where one has to reconcile large differences in constrained and unconstrained coefficients.

Comment: @AdamO Can you suggest a better example then?

Comment: I think the best idea is to follow the outline in the stata example: regression coefficients are proportions. You might, for instance, model CVD deaths in an additive risk model as a function of calories consumed of protein/fat/sugar adjusting for total caloric intake. That way, after standardizing total calories consumed (overeating is a dominant contributor to CVD), you can infer which calories have the highest attributable influence on CVD risk.

Comment: What? No, an example in which one has to compare a constrained and unconstrained model. And please explain acronyms. Not everyone is in health research.